# A derivative of RECOGNIZE that means incognito?

Tags: word-request

Does anybody know a word in the word family of recognize that means incognito? Like don't want anybody to recognize, not changing in a way that unintentionally make people can't recognize, so I don't think it's "unrecognizable".

Comment: "Recognize", "unrecognizable", and "incognito" share the same root.

Comment: @Jasper really? How is that?

Answer (score 3):

To be '*cognisant*' means to know, understand, perceive.

It comes from the Latin *co-* (together) and *gnoscer* (to know)

So you see someone you know, you re**cogni**se them. You make yourself unre**cogni**sable by going in**cogni**to.